# QGIS start-up error message: "Couldn't load plugin MetaSearch due to an error when calling its classFactory() method"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm an Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) user and I just recently upgraded my QGIS instalation (from 2.14, "Essen", to 2.16, "Nødebo").

I'm not a programmer and I know little about the details of how python works, much less about how QGIS and python relate, so when I get this message at start-up, I don't really know what to do about it:

```
Couldn't load plugin MetaSearch due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ImportError: No module named requests 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/jmb/.qgis2/python/plugins/MetaSearch/__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
    from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/jmb/.qgis2/python/plugins/MetaSearch/plugin.py", line 31, in 
    from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/jmb/.qgis2/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/maindialog.py", line 44, in 
    from owslib.csw import CatalogueServiceWeb
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/owslib/csw.py", line 27, in 
    from owslib.util import OrderedDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/owslib/util.py", line 35, in 
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named requests


Python version: 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) [GCC 5.3.1 20160413] 
QGIS version: 2.16.1-Nødebo Nødebo, 8545b3b 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/jmb/.qgis2/python
/home/jmb/.qgis2/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/home/jmb/.qgis2//python
```

> Note that I can ignore this message and work in QGIS without further issues.

Anyways, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

---

In case it matters, here are the commands used for upgrading QGIS:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

And these are the lines in my relevant lines from the `/etc/apt/sources.list`
file:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
```

---

> Note2: can this be originated by the non ASCII character in the QGIS version "Nødebo"?

Comment: please check in the issue list https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15368 btw as you can see the message is "No module named requests"

Comment: Indeed, but I didn't really know what to do about that.

Comment: Don't just blindly let Python install stuff on your system, i.e., as root. Check first if your package manager provides the module in question, so that you get the benefits of proper dependency tracking. Doesn't apply if you're on Windows, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same error, found the solution here: [QGIS issues](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15374)

Just run:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

to install the required module.

Answer (score 4):

In my case this helped (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the (experimental) version from http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/
Then install the Plugin via plugins > manage and install plugins > install from zip > your zip file

Answer (score 0):

For those using Windows 10, open the command prompt and use

```
pip install requests
```

Mine just worked!

Answer (score -1):

go to `C:\Users\your computer account \.qgis2\python\plugins` and delete all recent files (sort by recent date),  especially `.pyc` files.

Comment: ALL? you just deleted all plugins.

Comment: Anybody find a simple command line fix for this ongoing (at least 2 year researching on QGIS bug reports) issue? Thanks.