# Cannot install any plugins: please see error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

**Using QGIS version 3.4.4.
No issues with version 2.18.28**

When attempting to install any well credited plugin, I'm presented with the following error.

[image]

```
`Couldn't load plugin 'nominatim' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

TypeError: 'QVariant' object is not subscriptable 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/jamesbrett/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\nominatim\__init__.py", line 27, in classFactory
    return nominatim(iface)
  File "C:/Users/jamesbrett/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\nominatim\nominatim.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.myLocale = locale[0:2]
TypeError: 'QVariant' object is not subscriptable
```

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.4-Madeira Madeira, f6ddc62fdb

```
Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/jamesbrett/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/jamesbrett/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/jamesbrett/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/jamesbrett/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default`
```

When closing the window and return to the plugin installer dialogue, the plugin is shown to be installed but the checkbox is unchecked. When checking it, the error returns.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206434/qgis-start-up-error-message-couldnt-load-plugin-metasearch-due-to-an-error-wh/206466) is a question with the same issue but I do not know how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the issue is in **Nominatim Locator Filter** plugin. So, in **Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins**, search by **nominatim** and click in Uninstall (preferably) or Reinstall plugin for solving this issue; as it can be observed at below image:

[image]

If you cannot open **Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins**, change to following folder:

```
C:\Users\jamesbrett\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
```

and remove **nominatim_locator_filter** plugin folder before launch QGIS 3 again.