# GeomorphicFloodArea Plugin is not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I'm trying to get the plugin [GeomorphicFloodArea](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeomorphicFloodIndex/) to work but cannot.

I tried using QGIS 3.10 but got an error message, so I downloaded version 2.18.28 and it still will not work. I get an error message saying:

> Couldn't load plugin GeomorphicFloodIndex due to an error when calling
>   its classFactory() method

Not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: I would doubt whether this Plugin is supported in QGIS 3.x. You may try [Plugin migration to QGIS 3](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3). Alternatively check this article [A GIS tool for cost-effective delineation of flood-prone areas](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323155770_A_GIS_tool_for_cost-effective_delineation_of_flood-prone_areas) maybe Plugin's authors have compared some similar solutions, as well as inspect [`r.hazard.flood`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.hazard.flood.html).

Comment: Do you have both Python 2 and 3 installed on your PC? Check these threads [qgis plugin problem: Couldn't load plugin due to an error when calling its classFactory() method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285334/qgis-plugin-problem-couldnt-load-plugin-due-to-an-error-when-calling-its-class) and [QGIS start-up error message: “Couldn't load plugin MetaSearch due to an error when calling its classFactory() method”](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206434/qgis-start-up-error-message-couldnt-load-plugin-metasearch-due-to-an-error-wh).